# Unreachable catch block for ClassNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

Here is the code for simple login `Servlet` in `Eclipse` which checks username and password  from the existing table of database and  take it to home page if exists or send to login page. When I run it on server and put information in login page it shows following error. can you help for that please. thank you.

**1. Error to solve**

```
    root cause 


    java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    Unreachable catch block for ClassNotFoundException. This exception is   never thrown from the try statement body

    com.loginapps.servlets.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:90)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

**Coding**

```
    package com.loginapps.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

    import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

 /*** Servlet implementation class LoginServlet* @param <con>*/

    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String dname = config.getInitParameter("drivername");
    String uname = config.getInitParameter("username");

    System.out.println(dname);
    System.out.println(uname);

    try{
        Class.forName(dname);
        con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb",uname,"");
    }

    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

 }



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String uname = request.getParameter("txtuname");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("txtpwd");

    session.setAttribute("username",uname);


     try {
     pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where username = ? and  password = ?");
     pst.setString(1,uname);
     pst.setString(2,pwd);

     ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
     if(rs.next()){
         response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
     }
     else   {
         response.sendRedirect("login.html");
     }
  }

    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }




    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        doGet(request, response);
    }
  }
```

Comment: does you have the mysql jar in the tomcat(??) lib directory?

Comment: and can you post your `web.xml`\

Comment: Yes. I have mysql jar in WebInf/lib forder. Here is web.xml file. Thank you.

Comment: What part of `Unreachable catch block for ClassNotFoundException. This exception is   never thrown from the try statement body` don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you posted:
Unreachable catch block for `ClassNotFoundException`. This exception is   never thrown from the try statement body

Your `catch` block is the problem:

```
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception and is never thrown by the code inside your `try` block - see [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: When I removed that catch block it shows this error.                              java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException. Is there any how to sovle this one? thank you.

Comment: Did you remove the one in the doGet method? That's the one I was referring to and you can tell by the stack trace:  com.loginapps.servlets.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:90)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed catch(ClassNotFoundException e) in doGet method. It is working fine.

ClassNotFoundException is a checked exception and it will never occur in your doGet method code.